# Which could be normal vectors at the corners of cube?

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have an origin-centred, axis-aligned cube. Which of the following could be normal vectors at its corners?

A. $(1,0,0)$
B. $(-1,-1,-1)$
C. $(1,1,-1)$
D. $(1,1,1)$
E. $(0,1,1)$

I tried to calculate every possible normal and I got that A could be the normal. However, I think that multiple answers are correct and I do not know how to check if other answers are valid. Is there any rule to check it?

Comment: The normal is undefined at a corner, no answer is valid.

Comment: I think by corners it is meant by vertices

Comment: The normal is undefined at a vertex, no answer is valid.

Comment: if V1 = [0 1 1] ; V2 = [0 1 0] and V3 = [0 0 1]. then one edge would be v1-v2 and another v3-v1 so their cross product which is normal would be [1 0 0] so it has a normal

Comment: A point where you can find three normals doesn't have a normal.

Comment: You’ve computed the normal to only one of the three faces that meet at the vertex. The other two faces have completely different normals from that one. If your question is really “What are the normals of the faces that meet at each vertex?,” that’s a completely different matter.

Comment: Question just says which of the following vectors could be normals at the corners of the cube?

Comment: So maybe there is a way to check for which of the given vectors it is impossible to be normal?